# Create an array from device cli output in python

Tags: python, pandas, networking

I am still fairly new to python but ive done quite a bit dealing with pexpect and grabbing cli output from a network device. However, Im trying to make it a bit more user friendly by letting the user see a list of options to choose from.

I have a network device that would need to have a mac-swap loop put on it. I am using argparse to let the user specify the interface and IP of the device to use however, in certain cases, the user may not know which interface to use. I would like to parse through an output and present the user with a list that they could then choose from which would allow the code to use that chosen interface as the variable.

Currently, the output from the device would look like this:

```
user@hostname> show interface

interface table:

interface          admin  operation  user-label
1/1/bits           is     normal     --
1/1/bits/pdh       --     --         --
1/1/dcn1           is     out        --
1/1/dcn1/eth       is     out        --
1/1/dcn2           oos    ua         --
1/1/dcn2/eth       oos    ua         --
1/1/p1             is     out        UNI
1/1/p1/eth         is     out        --
1/1/p1/fp-1        is     out        --
1/1/p5             is     normal     UPLINK
1/1/p5/eth         is     normal     --
1/1/p5/fp-1        is     normal     --
1/1/p5/mgmt-1      is     normal     untagmgmt
1/1/p9             oos    ua         --
1/1/p9/eth         oos    ua         --
1/1/p10            oos    ua         --
1/1/p10/eth        oos    ua         --
1/1/ppstod         is     normal     --
1/1/ppstod/ppstod  --     --         --

[node 1]
```

I would like to parse through this list, im assuming using pandas (which I havent used before) or some other means to present the user with a list like this:

```
   interface          admin  operation  user-label
1. 1/1/bits           is     normal     --
2. 1/1/bits/pdh       --     --         --
3. 1/1/dcn1           is     out        --
4. 1/1/dcn1/eth       is     out        --
5. 1/1/dcn2           oos    ua         --
6. 1/1/dcn2/eth       oos    ua         --
7. 1/1/p1             is     out        UNI
8. 1/1/p1/eth         is     out        --
9. 1/1/p1/fp-1        is     out        --
10. 1/1/p5            is     normal     UPLINK
11. 1/1/p5/eth        is     normal     --
12. 1/1/p5/fp-1       is     normal     --
13. 1/1/p5/mgmt-1     is     normal     untagmgmt
14. 1/1/p9            oos    ua         --
15. 1/1/p9/eth        oos    ua         --
16. 1/1/p10           oos    ua         --
17. 1/1/p10/eth       oos    ua         --
18. 1/1/ppstod        is     normal     --
19. 1/1/ppstod/ppstod --     --         --

Which interface would you like to use?
```

Comment: pandas sounds like quite a heavy tool for this kind of task. Take a look at some python library for printing tables. For example `tabulate` https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/ (here is more comprehensive list of such libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data). I see that `tabulate` can number rows as well, so just make sure your interface list is of `list` type.

Or you ask here "how to read `show interface` output into an python object"?